# Is it possible to use Mutation Observer with a Three js element - A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webvr, collider

```
export class ColliderComponent {

  constructor() {
    this.observer = this.mutationObserver();      
    this.aframe(); 
  }


  //Registers the AFRAME component.
  aframe(){
    const __this = this; 
    AFRAME.registerComponent('collider', {
      schema: {

      },
      init: function () {
          console.log("The element to be observed is:",this.el);

          __this.observer.observe(this.el, {characterData:true, subtree:true, attributes: true, attributeFilter: ['position'], childList : true}); 
      },

      tick : function(){
        console.log(this.el.getObject3D('mesh').position);
      }
    });

  }

  private tick(){

  }

  private mutationObserver() : MutationObserver{
    return new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      mutations.forEach(mutation => {
        console.log("Changed position");
      });
    });
  }

}
```

I'm working on creating a simple collider. I'm going to track the elements that have the "collider" component and check if they're intersecting using `intersectsBox`. Unfortunately, I can't seem to make the MutationObserver to work. I'd rather use this approach instead of the tick, because it will start executing it per frame, instead when the elements move.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've also tried checking with the getObject3D('mesh').position. But that doesn't trigger anything when I'm using A-Frame's animation component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
el.addEventListener('componentchanged', function (evt) {
  if (evt.detail.name === 'position') {

  }
});
```

But polling/ticking via tick is synchronous and probably still not a bad way to go.

Comment: Ooof. The legend itself answering me. I'll give it a shot, and post back.Thanks!

Comment: The legend himself*

Comment: Awesome. Everything is working really well. I'll work with the component, and once finished I'll post it in Github.

Comment: Just to give an update.I have finally managed to get a simple collider working with A-Frame. After so long, OMG. It uses the intersectBox (tried with Raycaster, but couldn't make it work...). We shall publish this in Github no later than next week. Thanks for the help